# Thin Lines from PDF Figure in Latex get thicker when exported to final PDF

Tags: graphics, pdf, line

To have the best quality of figures in my document I'm using pdf images. But it seems that when the pdf images have very thin and/or transparent lines the final figure in the pdf gets messy, basically the lines get thicker and darker, unless the pdf is fully zoomed. This effect can be seen in the pictures below.

Does anyone know the root cause of this and how to fix it?

EDIT:
And note the inconsistency in the thickness of the lines in the zoomed out version. While the zoomed in version all lines are the same thickness, as in the original image.

Zoomed out figure:

[image: zoomed out]

Zoomed in figure:

[image: zoomed in]

Comment: it is very hard to answer without seeing anything other than the pngs posted here (which are anyway low resolution versions via the site upload). Are your plots vector plots are are they bitmaps wrapped as pdf?

Comment: In addition to the comments made by @DavidCarlisle, if the figures are vector plots, it's very often the case that the pdf reader is "normalizing" the thickness of lines to be a multiple of pixels on the viewing surface, and the rounding isn't the same.  Anomalies like this usually disappear when the file is printed at high resolution, but are quite obvious on relatively low-resolution screens.  If possible, try moving the image around on your screen, and see if there are changes in which lines are thick and which thin.

Comment: If you are using Adobe for viewing **switch off** the line thickening setting It leads to many producers overcompensating with zero width (1pixel) lines such that other viewer users complain they cant see the lines thick enough !!

Comment: Thank your for your answers. It is indeed a vector plot. I believe the problem is what your were saying, because I was opening the .pdf in chrome and it was showing this effect. But when I open it in document viewer it doesn't show it anymore. Another quick fix I did was simply having thicker lines on the plot, so it's related with the difficulty in showing very thin lines. Thank you very much for your help!